# Can't Style an Amazon AWS generated XML file using XSLT file

Tags: xml, xslt, amazon-web-services

Apologies for having to ask a similar question (helped very kindly by (Steffen Opel).  I am unable to get an xslt sheet to style an xml file generated by a call to Amazon Web Services (AWS).  I have many AWS calls and all were corrected by either changing the date of the schema (from 2005-10-05 50 to 2011-08-01) or by updating the Enpoint to 'ecs.amazonaws.co.uk/onca/xml'.

The call to AWS is:

```
RESTstringtemp = "http://ecs.amazonaws.co.uk/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AssociateTag=xxxx&SubscriptionId=zzzz&Operation=BrowseNodeLookup&BrowseNodeLookup.1.BrowseNodeId=676410011&BrowseNodeLookup.2.BrowseNodeId=676398011&BrowseNodeLookup.1.ResponseGroup=TopSellers,NewReleases&BrowseNodeLookup.2.ResponseGroup=TopSellers,NewReleases&Style=http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/topsellersnewrel.xslt"
```

As can be seen this generates an xml file and styles it with 'topsellersnewrel.xslt'.  The xml file generates successfully without the style specified.  However when the style is specified the file generated remains the same.  It's as if the xslt file doesn't exist.  However it can be found here http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/topsellersnewrel.xslt.file is generated

A shortened version of the xml file, generated without the '&Style=...' present, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BrowseNodeLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05">
  <OperationRequest>
    <HTTPHeaders>
      <Header Name="UserAgent" Value="Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0.1">
      </Header>
        </HTTPHeaders>
    <RequestId>1ABRF6WY8WSF5FM0EACQ</RequestId>
    <Arguments>
    <Argument Name="BrowseNodeLookup.2.ResponseGroup" Value="TopSellers,NewReleases"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="AssociateTag" Value="xxxx"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="Service" Value="AWSECommerceService"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="SubscriptionId" Value="zzzz"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="Signature" Value="f5mKeNVNEB5/sGIomPd/pXRC5Yfs5aCMchR5qgsvw0c="></Argument>
    <Argument Name="BrowseNodeLookup.1.BrowseNodeId" Value="676410011"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="BrowseNodeLookup.2.BrowseNodeId" Value="676398011"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="Operation" Value="BrowseNodeLookup"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="Timestamp" Value="2012-03-02T12:41:51Z"></Argument>
    <Argument Name="BrowseNodeLookup.1.ResponseGroup" Value="TopSellers,NewReleases"></Argument>
    </Arguments>
    <RequestProcessingTime>0.069159984588623</RequestProcessingTime>
</OperationRequest>
<BrowseNodes>
    <Request>
    <IsValid>True</IsValid>
    <BrowseNodeLookupRequest>
        <BrowseNodeId>676410011</BrowseNodeId>
        <ResponseGroup>TopSellers</ResponseGroup>
        <ResponseGroup>NewReleases</ResponseGroup>
    </BrowseNodeLookupRequest>
    </Request>
    <BrowseNode>
    <BrowseNodeId>676410011</BrowseNodeId>
    <Name>Games</Name>
    <TopSellers>
        <TopSeller>
            <ASIN>B006ZN5WJ0</ASIN>
            <Title>Mario Party 9 (Wii)</Title>
        </TopSeller>
    </TopSellers>
    <NewReleases>
        <NewRelease>
            <ASIN>B0073POVPK</ASIN>
            <Title>Pokepark 2: Wonders Beyond (Wii)</Title>
        </NewRelease>
    </NewReleases>
    </BrowseNode>
</BrowseNodes>
<BrowseNodes>
    <Request>
    <IsValid>True</IsValid>
    <BrowseNodeLookupRequest>
        <BrowseNodeId>676398011</BrowseNodeId>
        <ResponseGroup>TopSellers</ResponseGroup>
        <ResponseGroup>NewReleases</ResponseGroup>
    </BrowseNodeLookupRequest>
    </Request>
    <BrowseNode>
    <BrowseNodeId>676398011</BrowseNodeId>
    <Name>Accessories</Name>
    <TopSellers>
        <TopSeller>
            <ASIN>B006O8ODD2</ASIN>
            <Title>Skylanders Spyro's Adventure: Triple Character Pack - Double Trouble, Whirlwind and Drill Sergeant (Wii/PS3/Xbox 360/PC)</Title>
        </TopSeller>
    </TopSellers>
    <NewReleases>
        <NewRelease>
            <ASIN>B005CT3J66</ASIN>
            <Title>Level Up Stealth Media Storage Tower (PS3/Xbox 360/Wii)</Title>
        </NewRelease>
    </NewReleases>
    </BrowseNode>
</BrowseNodes>
</BrowseNodeLookupResponse>
```

The xslt file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xml>
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="aws:BrowseNodeLookupResponse/aws:BrowseNodes" />
    </root>
    </xml>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="aws:TopSeller">
        <xsl:variable name="browsenode" select="../../aws:BrowseNodeId" />
        <xsl:variable name="topsellerASIN" select="aws:ASIN" />
        <xsl:variable name="topsellerTitle" select="aws:Title" />
        <BrowseNodeId>
            <browsenode>
                <xsl:value-of select="$browsenode" />
            </browsenode>
        </BrowseNodeId>
        <TopSeller>
            <tsAsin>
                <xsl:value-of select="$topsellerASIN" />
            </tsAsin>
            <tstitle>
                <xsl:value-of select="$topsellerTitle" />
            </tstitle>
        </TopSeller>
</xsl:template> 


<xsl:template match="aws:NewRelease">
        <xsl:variable name="browsenode" select="../../aws:BrowseNodeId" />
        <xsl:variable name="newreleaseASIN" select="aws:ASIN" />
        <xsl:variable name="newreleaseTitle" select="aws:Title" />
        <BrowseNodeId>
            <browsenode>
                <xsl:value-of select="$browsenode" />
            </browsenode>
        </BrowseNodeId>
        <NewRelease>
            <nrAsin>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newreleaseASIN" />
            </nrAsin>
            <nrtitle>
                <xsl:value-of select="$newreleaseTitle" />
            </nrtitle>
        </NewRelease>
</xsl:template>
```

I've sorted out all other files but this one is beating me!

Please please someone help.

Comment: Have you tried transforming separately again, i.e. ignoring AWS for the moment to ensure the transform is doing what you want based on the two files alone? If I do that, I don't get the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), rather a dedicated result (though likely an undesired one at first sight) - what result do you actually expect semantically?

Comment: Hello Steffen, you must be getting fed up of helping me!  If I embed the xslt file I get the results expected but the browser shows no tags (only carraige returns) seperating the data. The start of it, copied exactly from Notepad, is like this -       
        True
      
        676410011
        TopSellers
        NewReleases
      
    
    
      676410011
      Games
      
        676410011B006ZN5WJ0Mario Party 9 (Wii)
        676410011B004JMZH4OZumba Fitness (Wii)      
    
THe data is correct but to tags are missing. (he format doesn't show when I save the comment!

Comment: Steffen - you can have a look at the output here - http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/XML_Index1.xml.   It should have 'structure' like (but obviously not the same as) this does http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/XML_Index2.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I was able to successfully run the provided transformation on the provided XML document.**

The result of the transformation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xml xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05">
   <root>

            True

                676410011
                TopSellers
                NewReleases



            676410011
            Games

                <BrowseNodeId>
         <browsenode>676410011</browsenode>
      </BrowseNodeId>
      <TopSeller>
         <tsAsin>B006ZN5WJ0</tsAsin>
         <tstitle>Mario Party 9 (Wii)</tstitle>
      </TopSeller>



      <BrowseNodeId>
         <browsenode>676410011</browsenode>
      </BrowseNodeId>
      <NewRelease>
         <nrAsin>B0073POVPK</nrAsin>
         <nrtitle>Pokepark 2: Wonders Beyond (Wii)</nrtitle>
      </NewRelease>




            True

                676398011
                TopSellers
                NewReleases



            676398011
            Accessories

                <BrowseNodeId>
         <browsenode>676398011</browsenode>
      </BrowseNodeId>
      <TopSeller>
         <tsAsin>B006O8ODD2</tsAsin>
         <tstitle>Skylanders Spyro's Adventure: Triple Character Pack - Double Trouble, Whirlwind and Drill Sergeant (Wii/PS3/Xbox 360/PC)</tstitle>
      </TopSeller>



      <BrowseNodeId>
         <browsenode>676398011</browsenode>
      </BrowseNodeId>
      <NewRelease>
         <nrAsin>B005CT3J66</nrAsin>
         <nrtitle>Level Up Stealth Media Storage Tower (PS3/Xbox 360/Wii)</nrtitle>
      </NewRelease>



   </root>
</xml>
```

Also, the XSLT stylesheet is accessible on http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/topsellersnewrel.xslt

**Therefore this problem isn't XSLT related.** Most likely other Url QS  parameters values cause the problem or it could be a security-related problem.

Please, contact Amazon support to get additional help.

**UPDATE**: The OP has asked in a comment to correct hes transformation...

The problem that causes unwanted output is in the following code:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="aws:BrowseNodeLookupResponse/aws:BrowseNodes" />
```

This applies templates to any `aws:BrowseNodeLookupResponse/aws:BrowseNodes` element, but the provided XSLT code has no templates that match such elements.

In this case the XSLT processor selects for execution the XSLT *built-in* template for elements, which is simply to issue `<xsl:apply-templates>` and this causes all of its children to be processed. This is repeated recursively, until a text-node child is encountered -- in this case the built-in template for a text node is selected for execution and its action is to output the text node.

**This is how all text-node descendents of `aws:BrowseNodeLookupResponse/aws:BrowseNodes` (that are not descendents of elements for which matching templates are provided) are output**.

**Solution**: Just add the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

**Now the produced output is**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xml xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05">
   <root>
      <BrowseNodeId>
         <browsenode>676410011</browsenode>
      </BrowseNodeId>
      <TopSeller>
         <tsAsin>B006ZN5WJ0</tsAsin>
         <tstitle>Mario Party 9 (Wii)</tstitle>
      </TopSeller>
      <BrowseNodeId>
         <browsenode>676410011</browsenode>
      </BrowseNodeId>
      <NewRelease>
         <nrAsin>B0073POVPK</nrAsin>
         <nrtitle>Pokepark 2: Wonders Beyond (Wii)</nrtitle>
      </NewRelease>
      <BrowseNodeId>
         <browsenode>676398011</browsenode>
      </BrowseNodeId>
      <TopSeller>
         <tsAsin>B006O8ODD2</tsAsin>
         <tstitle>Skylanders Spyro's Adventure: Triple Character Pack - Double Trouble, Whirlwind and Drill Sergeant (Wii/PS3/Xbox 360/PC)</tstitle>
      </TopSeller>
      <BrowseNodeId>
         <browsenode>676398011</browsenode>
      </BrowseNodeId>
      <NewRelease>
         <nrAsin>B005CT3J66</nrAsin>
         <nrtitle>Level Up Stealth Media Storage Tower (PS3/Xbox 360/Wii)</nrtitle>
      </NewRelease>
   </root>
</xml>
```

Comment: Dimitre, thanks for your feedback.  I'm getting a similar looking result.  However, 'almost' identical files are producing correctly structured styled xml files.  It looks as though the is only a problem with the 'BrowseNodeLookup'.  Any ideas?

Comment: Dimtre - looking at your result again, can you tell me why the result shows both the results picked out by the stylesheet and the standard xml?  It is supposed to structure just the browsenodeid, asin and title.  I was expecting a structure  similar to, but not tha same as, this http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/XML_Index2.xml

Comment: @Mark_54: Please edit the question and re-state the problem. As written, I understand your question as why the transformation is not applied. Now, in your comment you want to know what is wrong with the transformation -- why it doesn't produce the results you want. You must ask this in the edited question. You need to tell us what is the exact wanted result and what are the requirements that the transformation must implement. If you have given us all this necessary information, then many people will be able to answer with a working, correct transformation.

Comment: @Mark_54: Just add this template and the result will probably be what you expect: `<xsl:template match="text()"/>`

Comment: @Mark_54: I also added some explanation of your problem.

Comment: Dimitre - That is just the output I'm after.  You certainly know your stuff, nfortunately I don't, as you can tell.  Do I simply add that line of code or do I need to wrap it around the whole sheet?  Sorry to ask dumb questions but we all start somewhere.

Comment: @Mark_54: Just add this template as the last child of `xsl:stylesheet` (immediately before the closing tag `</xsl:stylesheet>`).

Comment: Dimitre - I've done this but with no success.  Would you mind taking a look at the xslt file http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/topsellersnewrel.xslt to tell me if I've carried out what you said correctly?

Comment: @Mark_54: After refresh I get the corrected XSLT and when I apply it on your provided XML document, it produces the result you said was the wanted. Maybe you need a reset/refresh of something? Or maybe the real XML document is quite different from the one you provided and this causes other issues?

Comment: Dimitre - Thank you for continuing to help me.  The real XML is longer but only really contains more results of the same categorie so should make a difference (it's this file: www.wiiuser.co.uk/XML_index1.xml)  I've tried a different machine but still the same result.  I'm at a complete loss what to do next.  It's very odd that you can see the correct results but I don't.

Comment: @Mark_54: I confirm that when I process your actual XML off that link with the corrected XSLT off that other link, I get the expected result. You can verify this yourself this. Just put thisat the top of your XML document and then view in the browser:  `<?xml-stylesheet href="http://www.wiiuser.co.uk/topsellersnewrel.xslt" type="text/xsl" ?>`

Comment: Dinitre - I tried that and the browser displays continuous text with spaces.  If pasted into Notepad it displays with carraige returns etc. but no element tags.  Do you see a full xml structure like the one you pasted above?

Comment: Dimitre - In fact the carraige returns don't show in Notepad.  If I remove the line of code you suggested I put in the carraige returns appear.

Comment: @Mark_54: I don't understand what you are saying. IE displays an empty page -- you must right-click and select "View Source". Then you see the result of the transformation -- as expected.

Comment: Dimitre - If you could possibly stay with me I'd appreciate it.  Perhaps through a chat?

Comment: @Mark_54: Have you ever been successful in performing such transformation: XML returned from the AWS service and XSLT from some other domain URL? This may be a connectivity/security issue

Comment: I've just checked IE and you're correct.  IE does show what I'm after.  I've been using FF and the page source doesn't display quite the same (it shows the arguments etc - which I don't want) so it has not helped identify problems.  It still leaves me with the problem that the stylesheet applied to the AWS call doesn't do anything. Perhaps that's another question (unless you know why this wouldn't work in the call?  If you aren't able to help I really thank you for your help.  I'll mark the question as answered.

Comment: Dimitre - Yes the sites I have have worked successfully for a couple of years and the transformations (about 10 files in each site) work perfectly well.

Comment: @Mark_54: My conclusion is that the XSLT code does what it is intended for. The issue is of security/connectivity and isn't of XML/XSLT nature. From here on you have to contact Amazon support and ask them if the `style` QS parameter may contain a URL from arbitrary domain.

Comment: Ok.  But there are 5 calls plus this 'problem' call on the same page.  All others work so I'm not sure it's security.  I do appreciate you're help and understand you can't stick with this for ever so thanks again.  I'll try to sort it out myself but I don't hold out much hope of getting help from AWS.  Regards Mark

Comment: @Mark_54: The only additional thing I can suggest is replacing in one of the files where its XSLT "works" this code and try to see if the transformation now is successful.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that with no success.  I fear that I'm going to have to close the sites down because I'm simply not good enough to solve this. What a pain in the ****.